# Rename [google-data-studio] to [looker-studio]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonyms

[google-data-studio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio) and [google-data-studio-charts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-data-studio-charts) should be renamed (and then be recreated as synonymous) to [looker-studio](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looker-studio) and [looker-studio-charts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/looker-studio-charts), since 3 months ago it changed its name.